# Regex/Java match fields with missing second quote

Tags: java, regex, etl

I have a pipe delimited records in several text files that I am loading into a DB.  As it turns out, sometimes a field will start with a quote but wont end with one, which causes the load to fail.  Here's an example record

```
||field2|"field3"|"field4|"field5"|||
```

Notice that field 4 is missing the trailing quote.  I would like to pre-process the file and remove the leading quote for these fields, but i can't seem to come up with a regex that works

I've tried lookahead and lookback combinations but always match `|"field3"|"field4|` instead of just `|"field4|`

I need something that looks for `|"` and some text that doesn't have a pipe, ending in a pipe without a leading quote.

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: the goal of quotes `"` wasn't to allow to include a pipe `|`? how do you distinguish between missing quotes and pipes in a field ?

Comment: an expanded test record would be ||field2|"field3"|"field4|"field5"|"fie""ld6|field7|"| and using everyones help below I was able to use regex ((?<=\|)"(?=[^|]*(?<!")\|))|((?<=\|)"(?=\|)) to give ||field2|"field3"|field4|"field5"|fie""ld6|field7||

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following regex

```
(?<=\|)"(?=[^|]*(?<!")\|)
```

matches a `"` preceeded by litreal `|` and whose next `|` character is not preceeded by a `"`.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sIf8fn/1)

Comment: this works!  I had tried this also, but i didn't do the nested lookahead and behind.  Looks like that was the key  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This regex will find all `|` without `"` before:

```
(?<!")\|
```

So you use it:

```
String result = data.replaceAll("(?<!\")\\|", "\"|");
```

After this code you will have the string with replaced all `|` without pipe before, to `"|`

Comment: Note that I can have a field with no quotes and this is ok

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negated class in your regex:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\|\"([^|]*[^\"|]\\|)", "$1");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BRWfkm/2)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `"`: Match a double quote
- `|`: Match a pipe character
- `([^"|]*[^"|]\|)`: Followed by 0 or more characters that are not not a pipe followed by a non-pipe, non-quote character followed by pipe. Also capture this in group #1
- In replacement just use back-reference of captured group #1 using `$1` to get field value without leading double quote.

Comment: Thanks this worked on the example I had but it failed on ||field2|"field3"|"field4|"field5"||"fie""ld6||field7|.  the expected result would be ||field2|"field3"|field4|"field5"||fie""ld6||field7|.

Comment: That is easy to fix. Just use: `str = str.replaceAll("\\|\"([^|]*[^\"|]\\|)", "|$1");`

Comment: Also note that look ahead and look behind are not really needed for this problem. Check demo link, this one completes the job in far less number of steps.

Answer (score 1):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/GqDJLT/1)

```
("[^|"]*")|"([^|"]*\|)
```

Replacement: `$1$2`

---

### Results

#### Input

```
|||"field3"|"field4|"field5"|||
```

#### Output

```
|||"field3"|field4|"field5"|||
```

---

### Explanation

- Match either of the following

  - `("[^|"]*")` Capture the following into capture group 1

    - `"` Match this literally
    - `[^|"]*` Match any character except a character in the set `|"` any number of times
    - `"` Match this literally
  - `"([^|"]*\|)`

    - `"` Match this literally
    - `([^|"]*\|)` Capture the following into capture group 2

      - `[^|"]*` Match any character except a character in the set `|"` any number of times
      - `\|` Match `|` literally